# Standard practice for distributing server certificate for users

Tags: tls

I have a Winforms app that users have to download and install on their machines. It connects to a WCF service(using SSL), hence requires the server certificate to be installed on users' Trusted Certification Authorities. Can anyone suggest the best practice for distributing a server certificate to allow users to download it from a website and install it on to their machines?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a certificate from a proper CA?  Then it would be implicitly trusted as the root certs already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Typically, the certificate store that contains trusted CA roots is a critically important element of the security in PKI.

It's literally the root of your trust chain. You cannot just have your users add a certificate there blindly because manipulating that store is something that is only done through a secure channel - something that, in your scenario, you have yet to establish.

That is why the best practice is to have you certificate signed by an authority that is already deployed on the client devices - usually a public CA but it could also be a private CA in a corporate network.

Answer (score 1):

Let me use an analogy: suppose that you are selling kitchen sinks. Installation and maintenance of a kitchen sink occasionally requires intervention of a skilled plumber. Your proposal (installing your certificate in the "trusted root" stores of the client systems) is akin to saying: "How do I arrange for my customers to send me a copy of their door keys so that I could send plumbers at any time ?".

Most customers would not like it. The "trusted root" store is *sensitive*. Pushing your own certificate in that store is asking for a lot of trust -- it gives you a lot of power, and makes the security of the machine subordinate to how well you protect the private key on your side.

The *nice* way to do WCF is to embed the server's certificate (or the certificate of its issuing CA) in the application code, so that the application may check that it is talking to the right server without changing system-wide configuration. This entails using a custom validator, as described [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733806(v=vs.110).aspx).

The method suggested by @Stephane (buy a certificate from one of the CA who are already trusted by most clients) is sure easier and probably faster, though.